# how to run specific xunit test cases depending upon the app.config key value

Tags: unit-testing, xunit

We have to use an `app.config` key in our unit test cases, but the value of that key is supposed to be different in the test cases. So depending on that values how to run specific cases? If one unit test case runs then other test cases should not run how to manage this programmatically in c#?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can follow is to wrap the use of your configurations in an interface.

```cs
public interface IConfigurationWrapper
{
    string GetConfigA();
    string GetConfigB();
}
```

```cs
public class ConfigurationWrapper : IConfigurationWrapper 
{      
    public ConfigurationWrapper ()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["countoffiles"]
    }
}
```

And then on your tests mock it with [NSubsititute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) or any other mocking library:

```cs
var configurations = Substitute.For<IConfigurationWrapper>();
```

```cs
configurations.GetConfigA().Returns("Config A for testing!")
```

Them you can use this mock(s) to run [parameterized tests with xUnit](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/).

This [project](https://github.com/raschmitt/cli-mail) of mine, has an implementation of this wrapper pattern for testing.